# Noob with HTTParty and parsing / accessing responses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rails-api, httparty

So I am BRAND new to the world of hitting and parsing API's, Using postman, I have been able to hit the api and get the response back, containing the info I need.

this is what's returned as the response.

`=> #<HTTParty::Response:0x1e2a8 parsed_response={"success"=>true, "error"=>nil, "response"=>[{"loc"=>{"lat"=>51.062831878662, "long"=>-113.88871002197}, "place"=>{"name"=>"chestermere", "state"=>"ab", "country"=>"ca"}, "periods"=>[{"timestamp"=>1600819200, "dateTimeISO"=>"2020-09-22T18:00:00-06:00", "tempC"=>15.14, "tempF"=>59.26, "feelslikeC"=>15.14, "feelslikeF"=>59.26, "dewpointC"=>3.63, "dewpointF"=>38.53, "humidity"=>44, "pressureMB"=>1010.6, "pressureIN"=>29.84, "windDir"=>"SSE", "windDirDEG"=>158, "windSpeedKTS"=>4.86, "windSpeedKPH"=>9, "windSpeedMPH"=>5.59, "windGustKTS"=>10, "windGustKPH"=>18.52, "windGustMPH"=>11.51, "precipMM"=>0, "precipIN"=>0, "snowCM"=>0, "snowIN"=>0, "visibilityKM"=>24.135, "visibilityMI"=>14.997, "sky"=>69, "cloudsCoded"=>"SC", "weather"=>"Partly Cloudy", "weatherCoded"=>"::SC", "weatherPrimary"=>"Partly Cloudy", "weatherPrimaryCoded"=>"::SC", "icon"=>"pcloudy.png", "solradWM2"=>204, "uvi"=>0, "isDay"=>true}, {"timestamp"=>1600822800, "dateTimeISO"=>"2020-09-22T19:00:00-06:00", "tempC"=>14.46, "tempF"=>58.02, "feelslikeC"=>14.46, "feelslikeF"=>58.02, "dewpointC"=>4.13, "dewpointF"=>39.44, "humidity"=>49, "pressureMB"=>1011.8, "pressureIN"=>29.88, "windDir"=>"SSE", "windDirDEG"=>157, "windSpeedKTS"=>5.74, "windSpeedKPH"=>10.63, "windSpeedMPH"=>6.61, "windGustKTS"=>9, "windGustKPH"=>16.67, "windGustMPH"=>10.36, "precipMM"=>0, "precipIN"=>0, "snowCM"=>0, "snowIN"=>0, "visibilityKM"=>24.135, "visibilityMI"=>14.997, "sky"=>44, "cloudsCoded"=>"SC", "weather"=>"Partly Cloudy", "weatherCoded"=>"::SC", "weatherPrimary"=>"Partly Cloudy", "weatherPrimaryCoded"=>"::SC", "icon"=>"pcloudy.png", "solradWM2"=>47, "uvi"=>0, "isDay"=>true}], "profile"=>{"tz"=>"America/Edmonton", "tzname"=>"MDT", "tzoffset"=>-21600, "isDST"=>true, "elevFT"=>nil, "elevM"=>nil}}]}, @response=#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>, @headers={"content-type"=>["application/json;  charset=utf-8"], "transfer-encoding"=>["chunked"], "connection"=>["close"], "date"=>["Wed, 23 Sep 2020 00:44:11 GMT"], "server"=>["nginx/1.17.10"], "pragma"=>["public"], "x-aeris-auto"=>["0"], "x-cacheaction-stored"=>["action__conditions_index_52ac6d0b54d5aa23bbb2c41fa8c79bbf ttl 60"], "expires"=>["Wed, 23 Sep 2020 00:45:11 GMT"], "cache-control"=>["public,max-age=60,s-maxage=60"], "access-control-allow-origin"=>["*"], "access-control-allow-methods"=>["GET, POST, OPTIONS"], "access-control-allow-headers"=>["DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range"], "access-control-expose-headers"=>["Content-Length,Content-Range"], "x-cache"=>["Miss from cloudfront"], "via"=>["1.1 2241406ac19fffc8f35d6ddef8e22f56.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)"], "x-amz-cf-pop"=>["SEA19-C1"], "x-amz-cf-id"=>["pnWOSthyXcky5YEtPxN34T5ViEStc8PPNJUasdvHemgUS7f6y7T5hg=="]}>`

Now i need to be able to access and save or display the data within the "response"=>[{...}] and this is what's hanging me up. I am not sure how to call the data within the various ""=> {} sections?

Any help here would be great, not too sure where to go to find the docs im looking for. when I do something like JSON.parse(response.body) It gives me this:

`=> {"success"=>true, "error"=>nil, "response"=>[{"loc"=>{"lat"=>51.062831878662, "long"=>-113.88871002197}, "place"=>{"name"=>"chestermere", "state"=>"ab", "country"=>"ca"}, "periods"=>[{"timestamp"=>1600819200, "dateTimeISO"=>"2020-09-22T18:00:00-06:00", "tempC"=>15.14, "tempF"=>59.26, "feelslikeC"=>15.14, "feelslikeF"=>59.26, "dewpointC"=>3.63, "dewpointF"=>38.53, "humidity"=>44, "pressureMB"=>1010.6, "pressureIN"=>29.84, "windDir"=>"SSE", "windDirDEG"=>158, "windSpeedKTS"=>4.86, "windSpeedKPH"=>9, "windSpeedMPH"=>5.59, "windGustKTS"=>10, "windGustKPH"=>18.52, "windGustMPH"=>11.51, "precipMM"=>0, "precipIN"=>0, "snowCM"=>0, "snowIN"=>0, "visibilityKM"=>24.135, "visibilityMI"=>14.997, "sky"=>69, "cloudsCoded"=>"SC", "weather"=>"Partly Cloudy", "weatherCoded"=>"::SC", "weatherPrimary"=>"Partly Cloudy", "weatherPrimaryCoded"=>"::SC", "icon"=>"pcloudy.png", "solradWM2"=>204, "uvi"=>0, "isDay"=>true}, {"timestamp"=>1600822800, "dateTimeISO"=>"2020-09-22T19:00:00-06:00", "tempC"=>14.46, "tempF"=>58.02, "feelslikeC"=>14.46, "feelslikeF"=>58.02, "dewpointC"=>4.13, "dewpointF"=>39.44, "humidity"=>49, "pressureMB"=>1011.8, "pressureIN"=>29.88, "windDir"=>"SSE", "windDirDEG"=>157, "windSpeedKTS"=>5.74, "windSpeedKPH"=>10.63, "windSpeedMPH"=>6.61, "windGustKTS"=>9, "windGustKPH"=>16.67, "windGustMPH"=>10.36, "precipMM"=>0, "precipIN"=>0, "snowCM"=>0, "snowIN"=>0, "visibilityKM"=>24.135, "visibilityMI"=>14.997, "sky"=>44, "cloudsCoded"=>"SC", "weather"=>"Partly Cloudy", "weatherCoded"=>"::SC", "weatherPrimary"=>"Partly Cloudy", "weatherPrimaryCoded"=>"::SC", "icon"=>"pcloudy.png", "solradWM2"=>47, "uvi"=>0, "isDay"=>true}], "profile"=>{"tz"=>"America/Edmonton", "tzname"=>"MDT", "tzoffset"=>-21600, "isDST"=>true, "elevFT"=>nil, "elevM"=>nil}}]}`

but again I am lost on how to grab the content with in it.

Thanks in advance for your assistance. Please do not hesitate to ask for more info if I am lacking!

Comment: where's yr Ruby code, fetching it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the json in a variable

```
example = {"success"=>true, "error"=>nil, "response"=>[{"loc"=>`{"lat"=>51.062831878662, "long" ... }`
```

then, for example you can do:

```
example['response'][0]['place']
```

If you need more help, please be more specific.

Comment: For sure, I really wasnt sure when i posted this what i was trying to accomplish.. ive figured out quite a bit now its just trying to sort out how to iterate each of the "periods" arrays

Comment: In your example I see only one period. If you have multiple periods, you can iterate like this: `example['response'].each.map{|p| p['periods']}`